# Numpy: Possible to ravel multidimensional array of unequal sizes?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

Apologise for the lack of working example, as it's quite hard to provide one for this.

I have a multidimensional array, but the dimensions are of unequal size. For example:

```
>>> print results_rmse.shape
(6,)
>>> for i in range(len(results_rmse)):
...    print(results_rmse[i].shape)
...
(224, 5)
(222, 5)
(224, 5)
(224, 5)
(224, 5)
(224, 5)
```

I would like to find the minimum of the final dimension of all the sub-arrays.

---

For example, if they were all the same size `(6,224,5)`, then I would do `min(results_rmse[:,:,4].ravel())`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand exactly the question, but if you have this strange kind of tensor (I'm not sure it is valid), you can iterate along the first dimension and evaluate the minimum for each mono-dimensional slice. At the end you compute the minimum between slice minima.

Answer (score 1):

With the 3d array:

```
In [205]: arr = np.arange(24).reshape(4,3,2)
In [206]: arr[:,:,0]
Out[206]: 
array([[ 0,  2,  4],
       [ 6,  8, 10],
       [12, 14, 16],
       [18, 20, 22]])
In [207]: arr[:,:,0].ravel()
Out[207]: array([ 0,  2,  4,  6,  8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22])
```

Now make a ragged array

```
In [208]: arr2 = np.empty(4, object)
In [209]: arr2[:] = list(arr)
In [212]: arr2[1] = arr2[1][:2,:]
In [214]: [x.shape for x in arr2]
Out[214]: [(3, 2), (2, 2), (3, 2), (3, 2)]
```

Treating it as a list of arrays:

```
In [215]: [x[:,0] for x in arr2]
Out[215]: [array([0, 2, 4]), array([6, 8]), array([12, 14, 16]), array([18, 20, 22])]
In [216]: np.concatenate(_)
Out[216]: array([ 0,  2,  4,  6,  8, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22])
```

(like the first, except missing the 10)

Notice that `Out[215]` has differing lengths, so `concatenate` is the only thing that will join them, not `np.array(Out[215])`.

We could also concatenate before selection:

```
In [217]: np.concatenate(arr2, axis=0)
Out[217]: 
array([[ 0,  1],
       [ 2,  3],
       [ 4,  5],
       [ 6,  7],
       [ 8,  9],
       [12, 13],
       [14, 15],
       [16, 17],
       [18, 19],
       [20, 21],
       [22, 23]])
In [218]: np.concatenate(arr2, axis=0)[:,0]
Out[218]: array([ 0,  2,  4,  6,  8, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22])
```